# Centering CSS Bootstrap Grid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, grid

I am trying to center an HTML element with a Bootstrap grid and I am having a really hard time getting it where I want. Here is my code:

```
                <div id="rentals" class="container pb-4">
                <div class="row pt-5 mt-5 mb-4">
                    <div class="col text-center appear-animation" data-appear-animation="fadeInUpShorter">
                        <h2 class="font-weight-bold mb-1">Container Rentals</h2>
                        <p>Here are the containers we rent</p>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="pricing-table mb-4">

                <div class="col-md-4"></div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="plan">
                            <div class="plan-header">
                                <h3>Short Term (6-12 Months)</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="plan-price">
                                <span class="price"><span class="price-unit">$</span>99</span>
                                <label class="price-label">per month</label>
                                <label class="price-label">Minium 6 months contract upfront</label>
                                <label class="price-label">Delivery cost additional (charged for round trip) upfront</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="plan-features">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>20’ Standard Shipping Container</li>
                                    <li>One Trip Condition</li>
                                    <li>14 Gauge Steel Walls</li>
                                    <li>Wood Floors</li>
                                    <li>Lockable Cargo Double Doors</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="plan-footer">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-modern btn-outline py-2 px-4">Apply Now</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="plan">
                            <div class="plan-header">
                                <h3>Long Term (12+ Months)</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="plan-price">
                                <span class="price"><span class="price-unit">$</span>89</span>
                                <label class="price-label">per month</label>
                                <label class="price-label">Minium 12 months contract upfront</label>
                                <label class="price-label">Delivery cost additional (charged for round trip) upfront</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="plan-features">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>20’ Standard Shipping Container</li>
                                    <li>One Trip Condition</li>
                                    <li>14 Gauge Steel Walls</li>
                                    <li>Wood Floors</li>
                                    <li>Lockable Cargo Double Doors</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="plan-footer">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-modern btn-outline py-2 px-4">Apply Now</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4"></div>


                </div>
            </div>
```

This code is making it look like this:

[image]

As you can see it's off to the right the first box is completely center but the second box is not. How can I center it using the Bootstrap grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 4 x `col-md-4` divs and these need to be sorted out. There are a couple of methods you can use to resolve the issue.

In this quick sample of a possible solution, I have removed both of the unused columns as a starting point for you to work from.  I've also added a Bootstrap `row` class to the parent div that also has a `pricing-table` class, basically so that your code is responsive as well. (You used a `row` class in the top `#rentals` div but didn't do the same in the lower section)

What's here is only a sample to build from: You can either add extra content to a 3rd `col-md-4` in the row, or if you don't have extra content then you could switch to `col-md-6` columns so that both `plan` divs are centred on the page.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
  
  <body>
  
 <div id="rentals" class="container pb-4">
    <div class="row pt-5 mt-5 mb-4">
      <div class="col text-center appear-animation" data-appear-animation="fadeInUpShorter">
        <h2 class="font-weight-bold mb-1">Container Rentals</h2>
        <p>Here are the containers we rent</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row justify-content-center pricing-table mb-4"><!-- UPDATED -->
      
      <!-- REMOVED <div class="col-md-4"> -->
          
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="plan">
          <div class="plan-header">
            <h3>Short Term (6-12 Months)</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="plan-price">
            <span class="price"><span class="price-unit">$</span>99</span>
            <label class="price-label">per month</label>
            <label class="price-label">Minium 6 months contract upfront</label>
            <label class="price-label">Delivery cost additional (charged for round trip) upfront</label>
          </div>
          <div class="plan-features">
            <ul>
              <li>20’ Standard Shipping Container</li>
              <li>One Trip Condition</li>
              <li>14 Gauge Steel Walls</li>
              <li>Wood Floors</li>
              <li>Lockable Cargo Double Doors</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="plan-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-modern btn-outline py-2 px-4">Apply Now</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="plan">
          <div class="plan-header">
            <h3>Long Term (12+ Months)</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="plan-price">
            <span class="price"><span class="price-unit">$</span>89</span>
            <label class="price-label">per month</label>
            <label class="price-label">Minium 12 months contract upfront</label>
            <label class="price-label">Delivery cost additional (charged for round trip) upfront</label>
          </div>
        <div class="plan-features">
          <ul>
            <li>20’ Standard Shipping Container</li>
            <li>One Trip Condition</li>
            <li>14 Gauge Steel Walls</li>
            <li>Wood Floors</li>
            <li>Lockable Cargo Double Doors</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="plan-footer">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-modern btn-outline py-2 px-4">Apply Now</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- REMOVED <div class="col-md-4"> -->
    
  </div>

 <!-- javascript -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <script></script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with `row justify-content-center` in your `pricing-table` div _ This should do the trick ; )

Answer (score 0):

You have to `remove` extra two `col-md-4`. one from `top` and another from `bottom`.
And just add `<div class="row justify-content-center">` this row above the grid. You can see it in the code given below.
`Justify-content-center` is `bootstrap` default class.
For more reference you can see below link: [enter link description here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

```
<div id="rentals" class="container pb-4">
        <div class="row pt-5 mt-5 mb-4">
            <div class="col text-center appear-animation" data-appear-animation="fadeInUpShorter">
                <h2 class="font-weight-bold mb-1">Container Rentals</h2>
                <p>Here are the containers we rent</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pricing-table mb-4">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="plan">
                        <div class="plan-header">
                            <h3>Short Term (6-12 Months)</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="plan-price">
                            <span class="price"><span class="price-unit">$</span>99</span>
                            <label class="price-label">per month</label>
                            <label class="price-label">Minium 6 months contract upfront</label>
                            <label class="price-label">Delivery cost additional (charged for round trip) upfront</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="plan-features">
                            <ul>
                                <li>20’ Standard Shipping Container</li>
                                <li>One Trip Condition</li>
                                <li>14 Gauge Steel Walls</li>
                                <li>Wood Floors</li>
                                <li>Lockable Cargo Double Doors</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="plan-footer">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-modern btn-outline py-2 px-4">Apply Now</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="plan">
                        <div class="plan-header">
                            <h3>Long Term (12+ Months)</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="plan-price">
                            <span class="price"><span class="price-unit">$</span>89</span>
                            <label class="price-label">per month</label>
                            <label class="price-label">Minium 12 months contract upfront</label>
                            <label class="price-label">Delivery cost additional (charged for round trip) upfront</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="plan-features">
                            <ul>
                                <li>20’ Standard Shipping Container</li>
                                <li>One Trip Condition</li>
                                <li>14 Gauge Steel Walls</li>
                                <li>Wood Floors</li>
                                <li>Lockable Cargo Double Doors</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="plan-footer">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-modern btn-outline py-2 px-4">Apply Now</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container" id="rentals">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
<div class="plan">
                        <div class="plan-header">
                            <h3>Short Term (6-12 Months)</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="plan-price">
                            <span class="price"><span class="price-unit">$</span>99</span>
                            <label class="price-label">per month</label>
                            <label class="price-label">Minium 6 months contract upfront</label>
                            <label class="price-label">Delivery cost additional (charged for round trip) upfront</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="plan-features">
                            <ul>
                                <li>20’ Standard Shipping Container</li>
                                <li>One Trip Condition</li>
                                <li>14 Gauge Steel Walls</li>
                                <li>Wood Floors</li>
                                <li>Lockable Cargo Double Doors</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="plan-footer">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-modern btn-outline py-2 px-4">Apply Now</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
<div class="plan">
                        <div class="plan-header">
                            <h3>Long Term (12+ Months)</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="plan-price">
                            <span class="price"><span class="price-unit">$</span>89</span>
                            <label class="price-label">per month</label>
                            <label class="price-label">Minium 12 months contract upfront</label>
                            <label class="price-label">Delivery cost additional (charged for round trip) upfront</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="plan-features">
                            <ul>
                                <li>20’ Standard Shipping Container</li>
                                <li>One Trip Condition</li>
                                <li>14 Gauge Steel Walls</li>
                                <li>Wood Floors</li>
                                <li>Lockable Cargo Double Doors</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="plan-footer">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-modern btn-outline py-2 px-4">Apply Now</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

see:https://jsfiddle.net/pjszxret/8/